# Blog Page 404 - regular expression for rewrite needs fix

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've got a regular expression head-scratcher and could really use some advice from someone that knows regex. My URL rewrite rule below rewrites URL requests for **/blog/customurl** to **/blog/index.php/customurl** - this works great for Wordpress permalinks.

```
Rewrite Engine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/blog/(?!index.php)(?!wp)([^\.]*)$ /blog/index.php/$1 [I]
```

Now I also need a separate rule that would rewrite **/blog** or **/blog/** (nothing trailing) as **/blog/index.php** without affecting that existing rule. Requests for **/blog** or **/blog/** 404 right now, but adding index.php manually in the address bar pulls up the blog home page. Ideas?

FYI In this case, I can't set up folder-specific rewrite rules using the .htaccess in /blog/ . I also can't use RewriteBase, so I'm really hoping for a solution that tackles this from the root folder with a regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/?$ /blog/index.php$1 [L]
```

This just says that if the URL is `/blog` or `/blog/`, go to `/blog/index.php` (and the `[L]` means "don't process any more rules").

Comment: thanks, i will try this out! i guess this should go above the other RewriteRule, not below it...